# ".check" for radio in JS

Tags: javascript, radio-button, checked

here's my code:

```
document.getElementById("frequencyweekly").checked = function() {
    document.getElementById("newsoptions").className = "activesubscription";
};

    <div id="newsoptions">
        <input type="radio" id="frequencyweekly" name="newsletterfrequency">
        <label for="frequencyweekly">Weekly</label>

        <input type="radio" id="frequencymonthly" name="newsletterfrequency">
        <label for="frequencymonthly">Monthly</label>
    </div>
```

I would like my .newsoptions div have class .activesubscription if #frequencyweekly button is checked. How should I do that?

Comment: It should be `.onclick`. `.checked` just sets the current state of the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`checked` is a boolean, not an event that fires a function, so you probably want

```
if ( document.getElementById("frequencyweekly").checked ) {
    document.getElementById("newsoptions").className = "activesubscription";
}
```

if you want that in an event handler it would be

```
var box  = document.getElementById("frequencyweekly"),
    elem = document.getElementById("newsoptions");

box.addEventListener('change', function() {
    if ( this.checked ) {
        elem.classList.add("activesubscription");
    } else {
        elem.classList.remove("activesubscription");
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: I'm not using `onclick`, but the more appropriate `onchange`, but you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something when clicking a box, you use the `onclick` attribute. Within that, you can check the `checked` property.

```
document.getElementById("frequencyweekly").onclick = function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        document.getElementById("newsoptions").className = "activesubscription";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("newsoptions").className = "";
    }
}
```